# What is the meaning of HID quirks that linux kernel uses?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

As the title suggests I would like to know if the actual meaning of the HID [quirks](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/410feb75de245664d66bc05ab2e2412751d10acf/include/linux/hid.h) used in the linux kernel is documented somewhere.

Some are pretty self-explanatory (e.g. `HID_QUIRK_ALWAYS_POLL`, `HID_QUIRK_IGNORE`) but others (e.g. `HID_QUIRK_HIDDEV_FORCE`) not so much.

Where can I find more info on this?

Comment: First place I'd look is the kernel source.

Comment: already did. Couldn't find any relevant info

Answer (score 1):

Example how to find out from the source, for `HID_QUIRK_HIDDEV_FORCE`:

Using an [online index](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.5/ident/HID_QUIRK_HIDDEV_FORCE), it sets [HID_CONNECT_HIDDEV_FORCE](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.5/ident/HID_CONNECT_HIDDEV_FORCE) which via a few methods ends up as `force` in [hiddev_connect](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.5/source/drivers/hid/usbhid/hiddev.c#L878), where it disables a check if the HID type is HID_APPLICATION_COLLECTION and the usage is INPUT_DEVICE.

In other words, it forces the hiddev to appear even type or usage are wrong on the HID provided by the device. So this quirk works around false data from the device.

It should be possible to find out what the others mean in a similar way. Yes, it means investing a bit of time following the call chain.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know I can read the code to see what it does but my question is if there's a documentation of all these quirks

Comment: Apparently not...